# How to process data faster in python from redshift?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-redshift, data-science

i am new to python ..
i have my data in redshift and i want to process data faster in python.
i am using python because i want to run various algorithms and also do various calculations on these data and this is not possible in redshift .
i saw tutorials but its taking too much time everytime to load in python.
here is my code:

```
import psycopg2

con=psycopg2.connect(dbname = "xxxx", host="redshifttest-icp.cooqucvshoum.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com", port= "5439", user="xxxx", password= "xxxx")
cur = con.cursor()

a = "select * from xxxx ;"

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql(a,con)
df = df.fillna(0)
df2=df2.fillna(0)
```

this is working perfectly well, but i want some method which could help me to process data faster..
can anyone please help me ?

Comment: what do you intend to do here? if the data from your data source is too big, you can make use of chunks to load it faster than transferring the whole data.

Comment: i just want to know various methods to load data , but from redshift , my data is in redshift amazon

Comment: Redshift is vastly faster than Python on a single server. Recommend converting your logic to SQL and running it in Redshift.

Comment: What do you mean by "process data faster"? What are you trying to do? Why do you wish to use pandas? If you provide more information, you'll get a better answer. Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , i have edited my question

Comment: i want to do various calculation on data and also run various algorithms , which is not possible in redshift , i have big data in GB . @JoeHarris

Comment: What do you mean by "process data faster"? What commands are "slow"? Are you running the Python app on an EC2 instance in the same region (if so, what Instance Type are you using?), or is it on your own computer outside of AWS? If it is outside of AWS, then the slow speed is probably because you are doing a `SELECT *` on GB of data!

Comment: look, i want my data to be in python for some analysis which are not in redshift , and if i am firing any query to get entire data or chunks of data , its taking me entire day to just fetch data from server , i want something like hadoop which can be possible in this , which can connect to AWS but m not getting exact sources which can help me to connect my aws data to python using hadoop like infrastructure @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Are you running the Python app on an EC2 instance in the same region (if so, what Instance Type are you using?), or is it on your own computer outside of AWS?

Comment: I am running python in my own computer

Answer (score 4):

If you are retrieving a large number of rows from Redshift (more than about 10 thousand) the fastest way is to use the [UNLOAD command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) to extract them as CSV directly to S3. You can then retrieve the extract and manipulate that in Python.

If you are processing a much larger number (millions) then I suspect you will be limited by the speed of Python. In that case I recommend using Spark / PySpark and the [spark-redshift package](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-redshift.html). Spark will perform the UNLOAD for you behind the scenes and your data frame calculations can be parallelized by Spark across a cluster of servers.

```
# Read data from a query
df = spark.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://redshifthost:5439/database?user=username&password=pass") \
  .option("query", "select x, count(*) my_table group by x") \
  .option("tempdir", "s3n://path/for/temp/data") \
  .load()
```

Comment: I did same from above code but now its giving me error "Failed to find Spark jars directory.
You need to build Spark before running this program." @Joe harris

Comment: It could be because you probably don't have the `com.databricks.spark.redshift` package to use for the format of your input source or because you didn't specify the location of additional jars at the command line or in a spark context configuration.  Try changing the format to one of [the supportive native types](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-DataFrameReader.html#creating-dataframes-from-files).  The format should be the same as the files you're working with, in S3.

Answer (score 0):

One package that may be worth investigating is [awswrangler](https://pypi.org/project/awswrangler/) which, though having a large number of dependencies, offers a convenient wrapper for many Redshift (and other) AWS interactions.

You first of all need to establish a [redshift connection](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/2.15.1/stubs/awswrangler.redshift.connect.html) eg specifying host, port, db info and credentials.

You then use this connection with inbuilt functions including [standard SQL queries](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/2.15.1/stubs/awswrangler.redshift.read_sql_query.html) and [unloads](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/008%20-%20Redshift%20-%20Copy%20%26%20Unload.html) which are more performant for larger data queries as mentioned by others.